# Why is it super.paint(g) and not this.paint(g)?

Tags: java, inheritance, super

Just a theoretical question about inheritance.

So let's say I've got a class "GamePanel" which extends JPanel.

I know within the class, if I call `super.paint(g)` , it will call the parent class (JPanel) paint method.

But if I create an object GamePanel, shouldn't it already *inherit* all of JPanels methods? So in that case, why doesn't `this.paint(g)` work? The current object should be able to access that method right?

If not, why does `this.setBackgroundColor(...)` work?

Because apparently `this.setBackgroundColor(...)` works as well as `super.setBackGroundColor(...)`. So it's almost like "super" can access all the methods while "this" can't?

Comment: I'd assume it's because you're inheriting from a JFrame. But I'd need to see the code you're using to know what the question is about exactly.

Comment: Related, possibly duplicate: [What is use of super.paint(g)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23434158/what-is-use-of-super-paintg)

Comment: If you're extending `JPanel` you should be overriding `paintComponent` and calling `super.paintComponent(g)`, not paint.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is use of super.paint(g)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23434158/what-is-use-of-super-paintg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It matters if you've redefined `paint` in the child class...you need a way within your `paint` method to call the ancestor `paint` method, otherwise it could only "call itself" like recursively from within that method...